# Android In-App Billing Version 3 get expired subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

the google api documentation states that you should call the method
    getPurchases()
to know currently active subscriptions, but is there a way to get from Google the expired subscriptions too? Or should I store the subscription informations on a custom server?

I'm doing a magazine app and, even if the subscription is expired, I should be able to allow the user to re-download the issues published while the subscription was active…

Comment: check this link: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#play-dev-api

Comment: check my answer below, it will help you to implement google purchase api in your project or your server side verification.

Comment: Did you have found a way to solve this? I am also struggling with this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course there is the way for the android application and your back end server to check your subscription details and it's expiration date and even if have access to cancel subscription manually from your server. Using "purchase-status-api", you can check it's expiration date and auto-recurring bill flag.

AFTER LOT OF SEARCH I GOT FOLLOWING LINKS,

[PURCHASE-STATUS-API](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html)

[AUTHENTICATION DEVELOPER DOC](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization)

[GET EXPIRATION DATE FOR SUBSCRIPTION PRODUCT](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/get)

**REFERENCE LINKS:**

[MORE LINKS TO IMPLEMENT GOOGLE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115381/unable-to-get-the-subscription-information-from-google-play-android-developer-ap)

[HELP TO IMPLEMENT FOR SERVER OR CLIENT SIDE GOOGLE API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427479/am-i-getting-the-steps-right-for-verifying-a-users-android-in-app-subscription)

Hope it will solved your problem.