# Validating google play purchases using Purchase Status API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-api-dotnet-client

I need to validate my google play purchases using the PurchaseStatus API..   i want to use the AccountService option...
[I did get this to work using the WebServer workflow, but that requires manual interaction, i can't use that on production  ]. 
For using Service Account, I tried two approaches that i could think of:

**1)** Token using Google Libraries + REST APIs..

```
credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
{   Scopes = new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher"  }
}.FromCertificate(certificate));

var task = credential.RequestAccessTokenAsync(cancellationtoken); 
// wait for it ...  with error handling.. 
var accessToken  = credential.Token.AccessToken ;  
string url = string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/{0}/inapp/{1}/purchases/{2}?access_token={3}",  packageName, sku, purchaseToken , accessToken ); 
// UseWebRequest agains that   URL ...
```

RESULT: the above fails with `401: Unauthorized`
That same code, works OK if instead of using the token coming from ServiceAccountCredential,  I use a token from Web Server workflow..

**2)** Next I tried using ServiceAccountCredential +  AndroidPublisherService..  so both google libraries:

```
// Same ServiceAccountCredential as above.. but now I initialize my AndroidPublisherService with the credential in this manner.. 

AndroidPublisherService svc = new AndroidPublisherService( new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer()
{ HttpClientInitializer = credential   });                               
var purchaseRequest = svc.Inapppurchases.Get(packageName, sku, token);
var purchase = purchaseRequest.Execute();
```

RESULT:  I get a

> [Google.GoogleApiException]
>   {"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nThis developer account does not
>   own the application. [401]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[This developer
>   account does not own the application.] Location[ - ]
>   Reason[developerDoesNotOwnApplication]
>   Domain[androidpublisher]\r\n]\r\n"}       Google.GoogleApiException

**3)** I tried a few other things such as trying to pass a User to the initializer... but they did not work..

What am I doing wrong?
How can I validate an **Android Purchase** using the `ServiceAccount` from **ASP .NET** ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps in this SO article- [Am I getting the steps right for verifying a user's Android in-app subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427479/am-i-getting-the-steps-right-for-verifying-a-users-android-in-app-subscription)

On a shorter note you need to create Application on the Google APIs Console and use the Client Id and Client Secret.

Then you need to get a "refresh token" which is never expiring and can be saved in the application for all future requests.

After refresh token you need to make a post request which will provide an "access token" using that token you can send a get request and validate the purchase.