# Cannot retrieve refresh token for google Oauth2

Tags: php, curl, google-api

Im using the following code in php to retreive the access token:

```
  $url ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$fields = array(
   "client_id"=>"{your client id}",
   "client_secret"=>"{your client secret}",
   "refresh_token"=>"{your refresh token 1/.....}",
   "grant_type"=>"refresh_token"
);

$ch = curl_init($url);

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute post
$lResponse_json = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

The problem is im receiving the following error:

> "error" : "invalid_client",
>   "error_description" : "The OAuth client was not found."

I have tried de-authenticating the app etc still to no avail.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you checked you are entering the correct client id?  I think you mean retrieve the access token.  You already have a refresh token what you need is a new access token.

Comment: the client id is correct, this retreives the access token. im  following the answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427479/am-i-getting-the-steps-right-for-verifying-a-users-android-in-app-subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was not enclosing the client_id etc... within " " in the array.  Curl was not sending the request properly.